# MongoDB $lookup vs Mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongodb-lookup

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539348/mongodb-aggregate-lookup-vs-find-and-populate) and other similar titled questions, none answer my question.

I was going through the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) where I read

> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >=
> 3.2. Mongoose has a more powerful alternative called populate(), which lets you reference documents in other collections.

How does `populate()` in mongoose work that makes it more powerful than MongoDB's `$lookup`?

Isn't mongoose a tool that helps nodejs users work with mongodb. If so how can mongoose have functionalities that MongoDB does not? Like `populate()`?

Does mongoose's `populate()` method use MongoDB's `$lookup` behind the scenes?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3683#issuecomment-334025713

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read the whole thread. Now I know that mongoose's `populate()` method does not use MongoDB's `$lookup` behind the scenes. And I have understood that the populate method does several trips to the DB to populate. I have also seen that in getting an array of docs `populate()` is faster. But why do people want `populate()` to use `$lookup`?

Comment: Make populate to use $lookup under the hood would allow people to use `.populate()` syntax over `$aggregation`. If you needs `$lookup` performance, then you must use `$aggregation` at this moment. Also it would be better if mongoose use what's available in mongodb instead of doing it's own "framework" function.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I have asked [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559332/mongodb-aggregation-vs-mongoose-virtuals) on the same topic. Kindly have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to a [github thread](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3683) shared by [Grégory NEUT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3337080/gr%c3%a9gory-neut) in the question's comments I have been able to establish certain facts:

1. Mongoose's populate() method does not use MongoDB's $lookup behind the scenes. It simply makes another query to the database.
2. Mongoose does not have functionalities that MongoDB does not have. `populate()` just makes two or more queries.
3. 

> How does populate() in mongoose work that makes it more powerful than
> MongoDB's $lookup?

In my opinion, there are places to use `populate()` and others to use `$lookup`. For more complex queries `$lookup` in an aggregation pipeline would work best.