# $lookup and populate, which is faster in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As you know, mongodb is a document oriented database, so I don't have relationship between 2 objects. With mongoose, it's have a function called populate to JOIN 2 collection with each other, so we have to use populate or $lookup to get data from other collection with a reference field.

But which way is faster ?

Sample:

```
Users: {
  _id: ObjectId,
  refId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comments'
  }
}


db.Users.find().populate({ path: 'refId' });

or 

db.User.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Comments',
      localFields: 'refId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'comments'
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB $lookup vs Mongoose populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557902/mongodb-lookup-vs-mongoose-populate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the hood, the mongoose's `populate` method doesn't use `$lookup` meaning that it runs multiple queries to database in order to get populated documents.

Taking this fact, we may assume that using `$lookup` in aggregate query might be more efficient and fast as it is a part of a single query and is processed by mongo engine on server all together. So, in theory, using `$lookup` must be faster.

However, it doesn't mean that you should not use `populate`. Mongoose `populate` is very useful and powerful and can be used in [various](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7575aa6d0e856b858a03fdb0af28718df46672cd/docs/populate.md) cases. In some situations you can achieve much cleaner and readable code using `populate` rather than writing complicated raw queries. And I believe that usually you will not experience any noticeable performance impact, so it seems to be a good tradeoff.

Comment: Yes thank you for more details. As my understand, with a simple query we can use populate, it's lighter, cleaner. With a complex business and must be fast, we'll need a aggregate.