# How to sort data based on entry of parent collection in mongodb using mongooose package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongoose-populate

How to sort data based on entry of parent collection in mongodb using mongoose package.

My schema is organised as given below

Profile Schema

```
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        fullName: {
            type: String,
            default:"",
            trim: true
        },
        school: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'School',
            default:null
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports          = mongoose.model("Profile",profileSchema);
```

School Schema

```
const mongoose     = require('mongoose');
const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default:"",
            trim: true
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports          = mongoose.model("School",schoolSchema);
```

My sort based on profile name works correctly from the below mongoose query

```
profiles = await Profile.find({})
                              .populate('school','_id name') 
                              .sort({fullName:-1})
                              .skip(skip).limit(per_page);
```

When I tried to sort based on school name it did'nt works , i have tried the code below, please help me to fix this issue

```
profiles = await Profile.find({})
                              .populate('school','_id name') 
                              .sort("-school.name") // Also tried "school.name"
                              .skip(skip).limit(per_page)
```

Comment: .sort({"school.name": -1})

Comment: @nimrodserok I think it did'nt works for me

Comment: The whole population mechanism is not very efficient, as far as I know. Consider using `$lookup` instead, I think it is more efficient and much simpler.

Comment: Please provide some ample data so we would be able to help more with the population...

Comment: Could you please add equivalent solution using lookup in mongoose. Sample data is simple as it contain only name field

Comment: And you may look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557902/mongodb-lookup-vs-mongoose-populate

Comment: For example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/lE4NE30wFmi